# Utilizing extracted word vectors from fasttext classification model in another classifier

Tags: fasttext

I am using fasttext to associate medical text notes for patients with admission decisions (classification). This is similar to sentiment analysis. I am getting decent accuracy. However, I also have structured quantitative data that I would like to leverage for further improving the accuracy of the model. The plan was to extract word vector embedding for each patient's text note (one vector for the entire text note) and combine it with the patient's quantitative data to build another classifier with better performance.

To my surprise, even without adding the quantitative data, I am not able to use the word vectors supplied by fasttext using the model learnt above to build another classifier that can match the performance of the fasttext classification model.

I am simply calling the get word vector function using the trained fasttext model and the same text notes used for training the model in the first place.

Am I doing something wrong? Appreciate any input. I am using the fastTextR package in R. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some of the relevant pieces of R code where you are seeing the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the question casieber. 

model <- fasttext(input = "myCorpus.train", method = "supervised", control = myCntrl)
corpusEmbedding <- get_word_vectors(model, myCorpus.train)
I see that fastText has two functions to get embeddings ("print-word-vectors" and "print-sentence-vectors"). Not sure if the get_word_vectors function fastTextR (developed nearly 2 years ago) can handle sentences or just uses the first word of sentence to return the embedding.

Comment: FastText sentence vectors are probably just the average of all the word vectors. maybe try Google's Universal Sentence Encoder. There are some good example notebooks where they do something pretty similar to what you described. In Python though.

Comment: Sure Sam. Thanks.

Comment: Just in case if anyone else is running into the same issue, utilizing the vectors from fastText's original code and "print-sentence-vectors" function, I am able to reproduce the result from fastText.